# Android - Animation on widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-animation

I started with a simple animation on button,
I am successful to an extent,

The problem i am facing is, I am able to animate the button but the position of listener,
Even after button is animated the clickable area is not animated , It is resting at the original postion

Could some one help me with an useful code snippet or suggestion

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android animations can not change the layout of buttons or view in general. Only their image will appear to move, but they will stay in the same place. After the animation is finished, get the Layout parameters through View.getLayoutParams() and change them.

Comment: setfillafter will revert the button to the original state, but my requirement is button must be animated to the end of screen and stays der. I am successful in doing animation, coming to properties I am not able to click on the button now, I can only click on the place where button was resting earlier. Is that clear?

Comment: Yes. Answer edited. Please vote up if you find it useful or accept it if you find it to be correct.